# Detect ListViewitem where rightTapped event happened

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Is there any way to get the `ListItem` from `RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e` without  `SelectionChanged` event and related sources because this `ListView` have `SelectionMode="none"`. If this is not possible with `SelectionMode="none"`, will it be available with other selection types, but still without selection change event?

Item xaml template below.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
   <Grid Height="56" Width="300">
     <Image .../>
    <TextBlock .../>
   </Grid>
 </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

Due to some experiments, I have subclassed ListView (with currently unused functionality) and also subclassed ListViewItem with handling RightTapped. Maybe there is any way to attach `this` to event? Storing this as selection result in subclassed ListView is a not good behavior I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
 <DataTemplate>
   <Grid Height="56" Width="300" IsHitTestVisible="False">
...
```

So now I see always `Border` as original sender. It was `TextBox` or `Image` before.

then at:

```
private void itemsListBoxRightTapped( object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e )
{
  Border clickBorder = e.OriginalSource as Border;
  if ( clickBorder != null )
  {
     MyItemType selectedItem = clickBorder.DataContext as MyItemType;
   ...
```

viola! Tapped item.

Now correct context menu for ListView is done ;)

**Update**: Windows Universal apps have `ListViewItemPresenter` instead of `Border`.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old question, but I stumbled upon it this week.

Crea7or's answer is correct in many cases (once you have the DataContext as they demonstrate, you can often use [`ContainerFromItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.containerfromitem?view=winui-3.0-preview) to get the `ListViewItem`), but it also does not work in two important scenarios:

- keyboard activation (Shift+F10 and the "context menu" button on keyboards will both trigger a RightTapped event [since Windows 8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.righttapped?view=winrt-19041#windows8-behavior))
- if your `ItemTemplate` contains other elements with their own [`DataContext`s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.datacontext?view=winrt-19041), like a `<Button>` (even implicit).

For the first scenario (*activated by keyboard*), `e.OriginalSource` has no DataContext. However, `e.OriginalSource` is already the `ListViewItem`! So you're done!

However, for the second scenario (*contains elements with their own DataContexts*), looking at the DataContext might get you a DataContext for a child—not what you want!

The most robust way of looking up the **ListViewItem** is simply to walk up the tree (adapted from [mm8's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41197947/788168) to a similar question):

```cs
private static T FindParent<T>(DependencyObject dependencyObject) where T : DependencyObject
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dependencyObject);

    if (parent == null) return null;

    var parentT = parent as T;
    return parentT ?? FindParent<T>(parent);
}

// ... in your code ...

ListViewItem lvi = e.OriginalSource as ListViewItem;
if (lvi == null)
{
  lvi = FindParent<ListViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
}
```

---

If you are confident that the second scenario does not apply, you can take a simpler approach to get the **ListViewItem** from an arbitrary event:

```cs
var listViewItem = e.OriginalSource as ListViewItem;
if (listViewItem == null)
{
  var dataContext = (e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement).DataContext;
  listViewItem = (sender as ListView).ContainerFromItem(dataContext) as ListViewItem;
}
```

---

However, the original answer to this question actually wanted to grab the actual object *backing* the ListViewItem.

To find the **actual object being represented** robustly—while handling all the additional scenarios outlined above, fetch the **ListViewItem** and use the [`ItemsControl.ItemFromContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemfromcontainer?view=winui-3.0-preview) method to get the actual object:

```cs
private void itemsListBoxRightTapped( object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e )
{
    MyItemType item;
    ListViewItem lvi = e.OriginalSource as ListViewItem;
    if (listViewItem == null)
    {
        // Use earlier definition for FindParent.
        listViewItem = FindParent<ListViewItem>(e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject);
    }

    item = (sender as ListView).ItemFromContainer(listViewItem) as MyItemType;

    // We have the item!
}
```

[ItemsControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol?view=winui-3.0-preview#methods) has some other very nice helper methods, like [IndexFromContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.indexfromcontainer?view=winui-3.0-preview).

---

Edit history:

- added clarification on how to get *ListViewItem*s from an arbitrary event.
- added more robust method for fetching ListViewItems.

---

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*