# How can I get an element from within a ListViewItem's ItemTemplate?

Tags: c++, uwp, winrt-xaml, c++-cx

I have a `ListView` that uses a custom `ItemTemplate` (doesn't everyone?):

```xml
<ListView>
  <!-- ... -->
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
      <MyGreatControl Thing="{x:Bind}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

`MyGreatControl` today has extensive keyboard handling code built-in, but due to some refactoring, I need to move the actual handlers to the `ListView` itself. However, I don't want to move all of the code in `MyGreatControl` to the `ListView` (for many reasons).

If I have an arbitrary `ListViewItem` (which, for example, [I can get from an event handler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65112803/788168)), how can I access the `MyGreatControl` instance in its DataTemplate?

```cpp
MyGreatControl^ GetMyGreatControlFromListViewItem(ListViewItem^ listViewItem) {
    // ???
}
```

*Disclaimer: I work for Microsoft.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`ContentTemplateRoot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentcontrol.contenttemplateroot?view=winrt-19041#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ContentControl_ContentTemplateRoot)!

```cpp
MyGreatControl^ GetMyGreatControlFromListViewItem(ListViewItem^ listViewItem) {
  return safe_cast<MyGreatControl^>(listViewItem->ContentTemplateRoot);
}
```

This also works for any arbitrary element—if you have a StackPanel, for example, `ContentTemplateRoot` will return the `StackPanel` instance you want:

```xml
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
    <StackPanel><!-- This is what you get! -->
      <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind}" />
      <Button Content="Foo" IsTabStop="False" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

You can then use normal visual tree navigation to find Children, etc.